# scrollable background in viewpager

Tags: android, background, android-fragments, android-viewpager, scrollable

I'm trying to create a highscore `viewpager` in my game.
In the highscore `viewpager` I would like to have a horizontaly scrollable background.

I found the `parralex` background, but I could not get it to work.
In another thread here on stackoverflow I found a link to a custom `viewpager` class.
This also uses `parralex` background, but I dont want to replace the entire `viewpager` class.
This is the [link](https://github.com/MatthieuLJ/ViewPagerParallax)

How can I get a scrollable background in a `viewpager` ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

implement ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener in your Activity and in onPageScrolled change your background to match the current position

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented something similar to what you want:

[AsyncBackgroundViewPager](https://github.com/SundeepK/AsyncBackgroundViewPager)

This is a widget that allows you to asynchronously load an image via a network call, cache it to a device. The same image will then be decoded when you need to display it again. Unfortunately, the widget has a dependency on a image caching library that I have written (which does have bugs in it). The widget does work though and it does pretty much provide a way to load a large background over a ViewPager.

You can hack it also to any requirements that you need. I will be uploading a version with out dependencies once I've finished it, which will be soon, so keep an eye out if you want.

Depending on how much of the background you want to show, you can simply change the on draw method to draw some specified width (currently it covers all of the ViewPager).

The project has a working MainActivity and you should be able to run right off the bat after downloading.